# iTextSharp difference between implicit explicit NewPage

Tags: itext

I use the onStartPage event handler to write a header, works great, but I need to know whether I issued a NewPage() or it was issued due to a page overflow. Is there an elegant way to tell?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A note on your using *the onStartPage event handler to write a header...* The method documentation says: **Note that if even if a page is not written this method is still called. It is preferable to use `onEndPage` to avoid infinite loops.**

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use the onEndPage to add the footer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written a page event implementation, and you've implemented one or more of its methods. You create an instance of this event like this:

```
MyPageEvent event = new MyPageEvent();
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

Whenever the `onStartPage()` is called, you want to know if it was called from within iText or from your code using the `newPage()` method. As iText uses the same `newPage()` method internally, you'll have to use a trick.

Add a memberVariable to your page event application. Something like:

```
protected boolean myNewPage = false;
```

Now add this method to your event:

```
public void newPage(Document document) {
    myNewPage = true;
    document.newPage();
    myNewPage = false;
}
```

Now whenever you want to trigger a new page, don't use:

```
document.newPage();
```

Use this instead:

```
event.newPage(document);
```

The `onStartPage()` method will be called internally for every new page that is initialized, and at that moment, the value of `myNewPage` will be `true` whenever the `newPage()` was triggered by yourself; otherwise it will be `false`.
I hope this helps; I didn't test it, I'm just telling you what I would try.

(PS: I'm the original developer of iText.)